# Amazon SES with two applications

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one Amazon account with my current production application running an elastic beanstalk environment which uses SES to send emails from that verified domain, let's call it www.original_domain.com.

I'm currently upgrading my application, which includes a changing the domain name.  I have set up a second application in my AWS account with a separate elastic beanstalk environment, let's call this one www.new_domain.com.  I have done this so I can test it along side in production.

Is there anyway to verify both domains to use SES where I can have both www.original_domain.com AND www.new_domain.com sending emails from their respected domains, or is SES - application a 1-1 relationship?  This would make the change over a lot easier rather than having to take down www.original_domain.com and re-apply to get www.new_domain.com verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit, upto 1000 domains:

> You can verify as many as 1000 identities (domains and email
>   addresses, in any combination) per AWS account.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html

Comment: Ok, great.  When I read that I thought it was 1000 email addresses (I missed domains).  Thank you